# Cognito form not loading in the browser

Tags: cognito-forms

I can't get my Cognito form to load. It just keeps giving me this error message:

> ### Invalid Form
>
> Our apologies, this form has been disabled due to suspicious content. If you believe you have received this message in error, please contact the original form author.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer for Cognito Forms. It looks like you are trying to collect a field with sensitive information which we typically block to prevent phishing attacks. Try to remove some of the fields from your form that are collecting personal information.